# Copy file inside Kubernetes pod from another container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to copy a file inside my pod during the time of creation. I don't want to use `ConfigMap` and `Secrets`. I am trying to create a `volumeMounts` and copy the source file using the `kubectl cp` command—my manifest looks like this.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: copy
    labels:
      app: hello
spec:
  containers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: bitnami/kubectl
    command: ['kubectl','cp','./test.json','init-myservice:./data']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-storage
      mountPath: data
  - name: init-myservices
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-storage
      mountPath: data
  volumes:
  - name: my-storage
    emptyDir: {}
```

But I am getting a `CrashLoopBackOff` error. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible.

let me explain : you need to think of it like two different `machine`. here your local machine is the one where the file exist and you want to copy it in another machine with `cp`. but it's not possible. and this is what you are trying to do here. you are trying to copy file from your machine to `pod`'s machine.

here you can do one thing just create your own docker image for `init-container`. and copy the file you want to store before building the docker image. then you can copy that file in `shared volume` where you want to store the file.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with an answer provided by H.R. Emon, it explains why you can't just run `kubectl cp` inside of the container. I do also think there are some resources that could be added to show you how you can tackle this particular setup.

For this particular use case it is recommended to use an `initContainer`.

> `initContainers` - specialized containers that run before app containers in a Pod. Init containers can contain utilities or setup scripts not present in an app image.
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Pods: Init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)*

You could use the example from the official Kubernetes documentation (assuming that downloading your `test.json` is feasible):

> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: init-demo
> spec:
>  containers:
>  - name: nginx
>    image: nginx
>    ports:
>    - containerPort: 80
>    volumeMounts:
>    - name: workdir
>      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
>  # These containers are run during pod initialization
>  initContainers:
>  - name: install
>    image: busybox
>    command:
>    - wget
>    - "-O"
>    - "/work-dir/index.html"
>    - http://info.cern.ch
>    volumeMounts:
>    - name: workdir
>      mountPath: "/work-dir"
>  dnsPolicy: Default
>  volumes:
>  - name: workdir
>    emptyDir: {}
> ```
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Configure Pod Initalization: Create a pod that has an initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container)*

You can also modify above example to your specific needs.

---

**Also, referring to your particular example, there are some things that you will need to be aware of:**

- To use `kubectl` inside of a `Pod` you will need to have required permissions to access the Kubernetes API. You can do it by using `serviceAccount` with some permissions. More can be found in this links:

  - *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: Authentication: Service account tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens)*
  - *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Access authn authz: RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)*
- Your `bitnami/kubectl` container will run into `CrashLoopBackOff` errors because of the fact that you're passing a single command that will run to completion. After that `Pod` would report status `Completed` and it would be restarted due to this fact resulting in before mentioned `CrashLoopBackOff`. To avoid that you would need to use `initContainer`.
- You can read more about what is happening in your setup by following this answer (connected with previous point):

  - *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: What happens one of the container process crashes in multiple container POD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589092/12257134)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/)*

> A side note!
>
> I also do consider including the reason why `Secrets` and `ConfigMaps` cannot be used to be important in this particular setup.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I tried HR Emon method. I was able to store it.  That didn't work for me because i was trying to copy it from my local file was not present on the internet. So as suggested by HR i copied it using Dockerfile and create init container, move it on the shared volume.